# Script runs echo normally, but prints nothing for looped echo

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to write a script that opens a terminal and loops echo in it. I have the following.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done; exec bash"
```

When I run this script, it shows three blank lines and then executes bash. However, if I run `for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done; exec bash` in a terminal it prints normally. Also, if I write the following it prints hello normally too. Therefore, I believe it's an issue with the for loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "echo hello"
```

I couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Why do you have `exec bash` at the end?  I'm not sure if you want to run a loop within bash and then start another bash shell...  Indeed, something is wrong with your code, but I can't put my finger on it...  You're getting 3 blank lines because it is the value of `$i`.  If, let's say, you put `i=10` and then run the loop, you'll get three `10` printed out, I think.

Comment: you need single quotes or `$i` will evaluate, therefore ... empty lines

Comment: @Ray I have `exec bash` at the end so I can look at the terminal after it loops echo. I was using sleep before, but I figured starting another bash shell would be easier. I'm a noob and don't really understand what you mean by `i=10`, but if i put `10` in place of `$i` it does indeed print `10` three times. It just doesn't make sense to me because when I run the code with `$i` in a terminal, it prints `1`, then `2`, then `3`. For example, `for i in hello; do echo $i; done` will print `hello` in a terminal.

Comment: @bac0n I tried `gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "for i in 1 2 3; do echo '$i'; done; exec bash"` and it still shows empty lines, unless I'm not noticing something else I've done wrong.

Comment: no, `/bin/bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done; exec bash'`

Comment: @bac0n It worked, thanks. But I don't understand what exactly is going on... I thought the usage of double and single quotes was just so you could have one inside the other.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).